# make not found with Dockerfile and centos:7 image

Tags: python-2.7, makefile, docker, centos7

I have a very basic Dockerfile which uses `FROM centos:7`, then downloads `Python-2.7.9.tar.xz`, and attempts to `./configure && make && make altinstall`.

I get the following error upon `make`:

```
creating Makefile
/bin/sh: make: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /root/Python-2.7.9 && ./configure -- prefix=/usr/local && make && make altinstall' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I've installing the following libs prior to running `make`

```
yum install -y zlib-dev openssl-devel sqlite-devel bzip2-devel xz-libs gcc g++ build-essential kernel-headers kernel-devel
```

Yet error still persists.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you please also post the Dockerfile? I'm assuming this is an error from a docker build? You need to provide some more context here.

Comment: Did you try `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` (think that should install `make` in the container)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A simple `RUN yum -y install make` solved the problem

Comment: To be specific: RUN yum -y install make

Comment: just install make ,cool